# How to make ListView inside of AnimatedBuilder?

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

I'm practicing an animated text tutorial from Youtube, and i want to implement it inside my Layout. In my layout, I have a background image.. so I'm using **Stack** so that my Animated Text is above the background image, and it must be scrollable.

it works perfectly without the ListView. But, when I wrap the Stack with a ListView...all the widgets disappear, it's blank. Please help me

This is the code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 final double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

return AnimatedBuilder(
    animation: animationController,
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
      return Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(....),

          //BODY

          body: new ListView {
           children: <Widget>[
            new Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
               new AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: 100 / 100,
                child: new Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage('assets/dashboard.png'),
                          alignment: Alignment.topCenter)),
                ),
              ),
                new Transform(
                  transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                    animation.value * width,
                    0.0,
                    0.0,
                  ),
                    child: ListView{
                      children:<Widget>[
                        new Container(
                         child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                'Have you subscribe',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 28.0,
                                    fontFamily: 'Sego'),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ));
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the error you got.

Comment: not error sorry, it's just blank. every widget are disappear(except appbar)

Answer (score 0):

Holy moly, it's actually just a simple blunder. My mistake is making ListView inside of ListView, which make it throws exception error. I just need to delete ListView inside the **Stack**..

```
   Stack(
      //(.....)
     child: ListView{
         children:<Widget>[
```